# return an array containing a specific string from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

Please I am not really good in javascrript, I have an array of arrays, with subarrays containing some strings, I would like to compare some part of the string to return the subarray containing the string.

Here is the parent array, containing the subarrays

```
[ ["1", "Love.Fish", "580 Darling Street, Rozelle", "11.97547", "8.36132", "0", "11.9669862,8.3664932|11.9639004,8.3680167|11.96465…3714714|11.9678258,8.3700981|11.9669862,8.3664932"], ["2", "Young Henrys", "76 Wilford Street, Newtown, NSW", "11.97804", "8.36153", "0", "11.973333416347666,8.352956771850586|11.9726617084…686332702637|11.973333416347666,8.352956771850586"] ]
```

and this is the string i have to compare with

`11.9669862, 8.3664932`
which is inside one of the arrays

this is what i tried

```js
var polygonData = [ ["1", "Love.Fish", "580 Darling Street, Rozelle", "11.97547", "8.36132", "0", "11.9669862,8.3664932|11.9639004,8.3680167|11.96465…3714714|11.9678258,8.3700981|11.9669862,8.3664932"], ["2", "Young Henrys", "76 Wilford Street, Newtown, NSW", "11.97804", "8.36153", "0", "11.973333416347666,8.352956771850586|11.9726617084…686332702637|11.973333416347666,8.352956771850586"] ]
 

polygonData.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
  // i am getting c from google map latLang
  var t = '"' +  c + '|';
 
  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    if (element[i].includes(t) > -1) {
        console.log(element);
    }
  }  
});
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You should use break once you have found the string you are looking for else it will loop over unnecessarily . Can you clarify one thing , are you getting the c as string from google maps?

Comment: yes i am getting c as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When searching for word do not include `"` as this is not part of string content. (`var t = '"' +  c + '|';`)
2. `includes` method returns `boolean` value true/false
3. you can make sure `some` method to avoid inner loop.

```js
var polygonData = [ ["1", "Love.Fish", "580 Darling Street, Rozelle", "11.97547", "8.36132", "0", "11.9669862,8.3664932|11.9639004,8.3680167|11.96465…3714714|11.9678258,8.3700981|11.9669862,8.3664932"], ["2", "Young Henrys", "76 Wilford Street, Newtown, NSW", "11.97804", "8.36153", "0", "11.973333416347666,8.352956771850586|11.9726617084…686332702637|11.973333416347666,8.352956771850586"] ]
 
const c = "11.9669862,8.3664932"

polygonData.forEach(function (element) {
  console.log(element);
  var t = c + "|";

  if (element.some((str) => str.includes(t))) {
    console.log("---> found ", element);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is wrong :

```
if (element[i].includes(t) > -1) {
```

You can just do :

```
if (element[i].includes(t)) {
```

Comment: tried this still getting all of the arrays in the parent array

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
polygonData.filter(x => x.find(y => y.includes("11.9669862,8.3664932")))
```